# Does adding a subtype to a creature count as entering the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Seraph Sanctuary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Seraph%20Sanctuary) in play, which lets me gain life when an Angel enters the battlefield. If I play [Call to Serve](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Call%20to%20Serve) on a creature, turning it into an Angel, does adding the subtype like that count as an Angel entering the battlefield, so that I gain life?

Comment: The question I proposed as a duplicate is about adding a type (turning something into a creature) not a subtype, but the answer's the same: the object hasn't entered the battlefield.

Comment: @Jefromi Agreed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, attaching Call to Serve to a creature you control **will not** trigger Seraph Sanctuary's ability. A permanent triggers "enters the battlefield" abilities when it transitions from not being on the battlefield to being on the battlefield, whether it be from the resolution of a creature spell, from the creation of a creature token, or from some other instruction. However, Call to Serve just changes the type of a creature that is already on the battlefield.